# Return null when dictionary with non-nullable values doesn't has a match

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I have a dictionary with value of type integer. When I populate my class with one of the property being of type `Nullable<int>`, I want to populate this property with value from dictionary based on the given product id.

How I can get nullable type when there are no corresponding values for given product id?

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public int? AvailableQuantity { get; set; }
}

var selectedProductId = Guid.NewGuid();
var products = new Dictionary<Guid, int>
{
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 1 },
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 2 },
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 3 },
};

var result = new OrderLine
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ProductId = selectedProductId,
    AvailableQuantity = products.GetValueOrDefault(selectedProductId, default)
};
```

Approach above returns `0` instead of `null`

And compiler fail to compile when I try

```
AvailableQuantity = products.GetValueOrDefault(selectedProductId, default(int?))
```

> The type arguments for method 'TValue
>   System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault(this
>   IReadOnlyDictionary, TKey, TValue)' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I am unable to change type of the dictionary. Dictionary is a return type of widely used method. This is first case when we need to deal with the scenario where product id can not be in that dictionary.

I would like to avoid to enumerate dictionary to change it's type to nullable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a C# Extensions which uses [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue)

e.g.

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue? GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
        where TValue : struct
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

usage:

```cs
products.GetValueOrNull(selectedProductId);
```

PS: This extension also works for other types than `int`, e.g. `decimal`, `bool` and other struct types

Comment: Nice generic version ;)

Comment: Is this not the same as GetValueOrDefault method already in System.Collection namespace?

Comment: @Morten_564834 I was also thinking that, but in this case `GetValueOrDefault ` will return the type `int` and value `0` and not the requested `null`. The typed is here `new Dictionary<Guid, int>` and not `new Dictionary<Guid, int?>`

Comment: @Julian yep thanks, I also needed a nullable argument new Dictionary<Guid, string?> which GetValueOrDefault does not have.

Answer (score 1):

If you doing this only once - use ternary operator

```
Quantity = products.TryGetValue(productId, out var qty) ? qty : default(int?)
```

If you going to do it in multiple places wrap code above into an extension method

Answer (score 0):

You get default value 0, because it is the default value of `int` (not nullable).

To get default value of `null` change type of the value in the dictionary to `int?` (nullable):

```
var products = new Dictionary<Guid, int?>
{
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 1 },
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 2 },
    { Guid.NewGuid(), 3 },
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to change type of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
var products = new Dictionary<Guid, int?>
{
{ Guid.NewGuid(), 1 },
{ Guid.NewGuid(), 2 },
{ Guid.NewGuid(), 3 },
};
```